# How to filter Json Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**Json Obj :**

```
"[{ID:1, Region:"India", ParentRegion:"All"}, {ID:2, Region:"Maharashtra", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:3, Region:"Delhi & NCR", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:4, Region:"Andra Pradesh", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:5, Region:"Arunachal Pradesh", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:6, Region:"Assam", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:7, Region:"Bihar", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:8, Region:"Chhattisgarh", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:9, Region:"Goa", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:10, Region:"Gujarat", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:11, Region:"Haryana", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:12, Region:"Himachal Pradesh", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:13, Region:"Jammu and Kashmir", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:14, Region:"Jharkhand", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:15, Region:"Karnataka", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:16, Region:"Kerala", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:17, Region:"Madya Pradesh", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:18, Region:"Manipur", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:19, Region:"Meghalaya", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:20, Region:"Mizoram", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:21, Region:"Nagaland", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:22, Region:"Orissa", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:23, Region:"Punjab", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:24, Region:"Rajasthan", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:25, Region:"Sikkim", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:26, Region:"Tamil Nadu", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:27, Region:"Tripura", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:28, Region:"Uttaranchal", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:29, Region:"Uttar Pradesh", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:30, Region:"West Bengal", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:31, Region:"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:32, Region:"Chandigarh", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:33, Region:"Dadra and Nagar Haveli", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:34, Region:"Daman and Diu", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:35, Region:"Lakshadeep", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:36, Region:"Pondicherry", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:37, Region:"Corporate office & Registered office", ParentRegion:"Maharashtra"}, {ID:38, Region:"Consists of regions in Maharashtra other than Mumbai", ParentRegion:"Maharashtra"}]"
```

I am trying to filter this on condition such that `var ObjSubset= where Obj.ParentRegion="Maharashtra"`

This is what I have tried:

```
var arr = jQuery.grep(Obj, function(index, value) {
    return (value.ParentRegion == $('#drpcity').val()); // value of drpcity is Maharashtra
});
```

But it arr seems to be entire Obj rather than subset of Obj

Comment: Are you very sure that `$('#drpcity').val()` is equal to `Maharashtra`?

Comment: Have you parsed the JSON string?

Comment: @Arbaaz try `logging` inside the `grep`. Both `index` and `value`

Comment: I have parsed the string.. i used `toSource` to get string in console.log so i can paste it here.  

I am sure its Maharashtra because i used alert

Comment: looks like your JSON string itself is wrong, try jsonlint.com and verify if it is fine. expected format is "[{"ID":1, "Region":"India", "ParentRegion":"All"}]"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function arguments are wrong

> function
>   Type: Function( Object elementOfArray, Integer indexInArray ) => Boolean
>   The function to process each item against. The first argument to the function is the item, and the second argument is the index. The function should return a Boolean value.  this will be the global window object.[Detail](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/)

```
var Obj = [{ ID: 1, Region: "India", ParentRegion: "All" }, { ID: 2, Region: "Maharashtra", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 3, Region: "Delhi & NCR", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 4, Region: "Andra Pradesh", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 5, Region: "Arunachal Pradesh", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 6, Region: "Assam", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 7, Region: "Bihar", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 8, Region: "Chhattisgarh", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 9, Region: "Goa", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 10, Region: "Gujarat", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 11, Region: "Haryana", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 12, Region: "Himachal Pradesh", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 13, Region: "Jammu and Kashmir", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 14, Region: "Jharkhand", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 15, Region: "Karnataka", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 16, Region: "Kerala", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 17, Region: "Madya Pradesh", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 18, Region: "Manipur", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 19, Region: "Meghalaya", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 20, Region: "Mizoram", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 21, Region: "Nagaland", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 22, Region: "Orissa", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 23, Region: "Punjab", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 24, Region: "Rajasthan", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 25, Region: "Sikkim", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 26, Region: "Tamil Nadu", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 27, Region: "Tripura", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 28, Region: "Uttaranchal", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 29, Region: "Uttar Pradesh", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 30, Region: "West Bengal", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 31, Region: "Andaman and Nicobar Islands", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 32, Region: "Chandigarh", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 33, Region: "Dadra and Nagar Haveli", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 34, Region: "Daman and Diu", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 35, Region: "Lakshadeep", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 36, Region: "Pondicherry", ParentRegion: "India" }, { ID: 37, Region: "Corporate office & Registered office", ParentRegion: "Maharashtra" }, { ID: 38, Region: "Consists of regions in Maharashtra other than Mumbai", ParentRegion: "Maharashtra" }];

var arr = jQuery.grep(Obj, function (Obj, index) {
    return (Obj.ParentRegion == $('#drpcity').val());// value of drpcity is Maharashtra
});
console.log(arr);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hfwum8yt/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Your object is a string but not JSON so you can use Function object to parse it first:

```
var input = '[{ID:1, Region:"India", ParentRegion:"All"}, {ID:2, Region:"Maharashtra", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:3, Region:"Delhi & NCR", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:4, Region:"Andra Pradesh", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:5, Region:"Arunachal Pradesh", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:6, Region:"Assam", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:7, Region:"Bihar", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:8, Region:"Chhattisgarh", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:9, Region:"Goa", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:10, Region:"Gujarat", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:11, Region:"Haryana", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:12, Region:"Himachal Pradesh", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:13, Region:"Jammu and Kashmir", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:14, Region:"Jharkhand", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:15, Region:"Karnataka", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:16, Region:"Kerala", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:17, Region:"Madya Pradesh", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:18, Region:"Manipur", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:19, Region:"Meghalaya", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:20, Region:"Mizoram", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:21, Region:"Nagaland", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:22, Region:"Orissa", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:23, Region:"Punjab", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:24, Region:"Rajasthan", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:25, Region:"Sikkim", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:26, Region:"Tamil Nadu", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:27, Region:"Tripura", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:28, Region:"Uttaranchal", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:29, Region:"Uttar Pradesh", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:30, Region:"West Bengal", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:31, Region:"Andaman and Nicobar Islands", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:32, Region:"Chandigarh", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:33, Region:"Dadra and Nagar Haveli", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:34, Region:"Daman and Diu", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:35, Region:"Lakshadeep", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:36, Region:"Pondicherry", ParentRegion:"India"}, {ID:37, Region:"Corporate office & Registered office", ParentRegion:"Maharashtra"}, {ID:38, Region:"Consists of regions in Maharashtra other than Mumbai", ParentRegion:"Maharashtra"}]';

var array = new Function('', 'return ' + input + ';')();
```

Comment: @Vohuman keys are not in quotes, JSON.parse will throw error.

Comment: Yes, didn't notice that. That's not valid JSON. But instead of evaling the string the OP should consider fixing the json-generator. Edit: "i used toSource to get string in console.log so i can paste it here."

Answer (score 0):

use js array filter:

parse the string to json:

```
var Obj =JSON.parse(Obj);

var ObjSubset = Obj.filter(function(item){
    return item.ParentRegion == $('#drpcity').val()
})
```

Comment: this is an array of objects, not an object;